# Qt QML Put element above a Drawer

Tags: qt, qml, qt5.15

I'm struggling with a very basic question..

Using QT 5.15.2:

We have a simple application with one main window and 2-3 sub-window (1 level down from main). The main window consists of a content item, a header and some menu-flaps distributed across the main window. So Far the sub-pages were opened with a drawer element.

However, the drawer overlays the flaps and header once opened and we need to re-instanciate the flaps and header within the drawer to have it visible. This is not really nice. Is there any way to define the z-level on which the drawer is opened? (apparently setting z doesn't work).

```
Item{
  id: id_mainWindow
  z: 0
  Drawer{
    id: id_subMenu1
    anchors.fill: parent
    z: 1
    
    /* Not so nice workaround */
    Button{
      id: id_subClose
      z: 100
      onClicked{
        id_subMenu1.close()
      }
    }
  }

  /* Unfortunately, this one gets hidden once, the drawer is open */
  Button{
    id: id_subOpenClose
    z: 100
    onClicked{
      if( id_subMenu1.open ){
        id_subMenu1.close()
      } else {
        id_subMenu1.open()
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-drawer.html#details, the second example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that a `Drawer` is not the right component for this job as it is technically a `Popup`. It might be worth checking out the [TabBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tabbar.html) component instead.

Nevertheless here's a re-write of your code so that your `Drawer` opens without covering your `id_subOpenClose` button.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

Rectangle {
    id: id_mainWindow
  
    anchors.fill: parent
  
    Drawer {
        id: id_subMenu1
    
        /*
        Set the Drawer's height and y position so that it does not cover your button
        */
        y: id_subOpenClose.height
        height: id_mainWindow.height - id_subOpenClose.height
        width: id_mainWindow.width

        // Do not dim background
        dim: false
        
        // Set this to zero if you want no shadow
        Material.elevation: 2
    
        edge: Qt.RightEdge
    
        Label {
            text: 'Hello World'
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

    /* 
    This is your header button that was getting hidden
    Here it stays as if it were part of a global header and does not get hidden by
    the Drawer.
    */
    Button{
        id: id_subOpenClose
        text: id_subMenu1.visible? 'close': 'open'
        onClicked: id_subMenu1.visible? id_subMenu1.close(): id_subMenu1.open()
    }
}
```

For an interactive WASM example of the above see [here](https://www.canonic.com/#https://playground.canonic.com/bdaad0bf-7aa4-4de9-8ab6-ffe0ab96774c/qt-qml-put-element-above-a-drawer).